# Foreign Keys clash with related field in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I'm working on a model class that will represent the relationship of one family member to another (part of a geneology feature)

My Class is:

```
class FamilyLink(models.Model):
    from_legacy = models.ForeignKey(Legacy)
    to_legacy = models.ForeignKey(Legacy)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("from_legacy", "to_legacy")
```

When I try and migrate I get the following error message:

> CommandError: One or more models did not validate: archive.familylink:
>   Accessor for field 'from_legacy' clashes with related field
>   'Legacy.familylink_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition
>   for 'from_legacy'. archive.familylink: Accessor for field 'to_legacy'
>   clashes with related field 'Legacy.familylink_set'. Add a related_name
>   argument to the definition for 'to_legacy'.

It seem my issue is having two foreignKey's in the same class both pointing to the same class (in this case the "Legacy" class). Does anyone know how I can be resolve/work around this?

I appreciate the thoughts and expertise.

Comment: Have you tried adding the related_name arguments like it asks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is quite explanatory:

```
class FamilyLink(models.Model):
    from_legacy = models.ForeignKey(Legacy, related_name = 'familylink_from_legacy')
    to_legacy = models.ForeignKey(Legacy, related_name = 'familylink_to_legacy')
```

By default, if no `related_name` attribute is set, the relatedname is set to `familylink_set` and since 2 different fields from the same relation, it causes the issues.

Read more on [`related_name` attribute here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: Worked great! Thanks for the feedback. I'll do a better job next time reading/working through the error message.